# ReportLab - Python - Duvida com escrita da data (date)

Tags: python-3.x, django

Pessoal estou com duvidas no reportlab.

Aplicação Python 3 / Django

Tenho um model `Pessoa` que contem um campo `data de nascimento` que é do tipo `DateTimeField`.
Estou tentando escrever a data de nascimento no PDF mas da erro.
Lembrando que a data vem do banco de dados.

Outros campos como Nome, cidade, endereco, etc estao escrevendo no PDF corretamente.

```
p = Pessoa.objects.get(pk=pk)
c.drawString(200, 630, p.data_nascimento)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o ReportLab (http://www.reportlab.com/)

Comment: Sobre o segundo problema, tem mais a ver com o navegador do cliente, ou algo em Javascript. Mas não será feita através do backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.datetime object has no attribute 'decode'`

Esse erro quer dizer que um objeto da classe `datetime.datetime` está sendo chamado, em algum lugar, com o atributo/método `decode`.

O método `decode`, no Python3, é utilizado pela classe bytes para converter para string.

Segue o exemplo:

```
>>> s = b'Oi'
>>> type(s)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> s = s.decode()
>>> s
'Oi'
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
```

Para resolver o seu problema, acredito que a melhor forma é transformar`p.data_nascimento`(um objeto da classe datetime.datetime) para bytes ou str antes de enviar para a função drawString. Para isso, utilize [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

```
p = Pessoa.objects.get(pk=pk)
c.drawString(200, 630, p.data_nascimento.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: muito obrigado. Era isso mesmo.
Eu ate pesqusei no google, mas nao estava sabendo colocar esse strftime .